# on change method not filtering the correct date

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have been working on a function that filters by date. I got it working with an click event, but I don't need them as buttons. It has to be a select option. I would think that all you would do is change the method from click to 'change' but that doesn't seem to be working. It will only display 'September' (the last month).

Below is a 'fiddle' that I made (I can also post the code). If you un-comment the 'click' inside the jQuery object and `appendTo($options)`. It will render buttons, which works.

On aside note, I would like to know if or how I could use the 'change' method inside the jQuery object. Like how I'm using the 'click' method.

https://jsfiddle.net/p689tk9q/2/

Comment: Your fiddle link isn't correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem was that `tagName` from your `each` function doesn't exist within the on change handler.  When the change event is fired, it's given `this`, which is the element that was the instigator of the event.  That's where you need to get your value from.

Your code was attaching an event handler to all select elements each time it went through the loop. So, the last time it went throught the loop, it attached an event handler that set the filter to the last tagName it saw, which was September.

We only need to attach the event handler once and then check `$(this).val()` to see what is picked in the select.

```
      $.each(tagged, function(tagName) {
        $('<option/>', {
          text: tagName
        }).appendTo($selectOptions);
      });

       $selectOptions.on('change', function() {
          $eventDate
          .fadeOut()
          .filter(tagged[$(this).val()])
          .fadeIn();
      });
```

Also, your `$selectOptions` was set to `$('select')`.  When you are appending each `tagName` to `$selectOptions`, you would append to every select on the page.  Currently you only have one, but that's the type of thing that bites you later on.  I changed it to:

```
$selectOptions = $('#sort_month select'),
```

And finally, it bugged me that there wasn't an all option selected when I was seeing all the data.  So, I added it to the listbox and updated the list when the All button was pushed.  I also added a check to make All work from the dropdown.-

```
  $selectOptions.on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 'All') {
      $eventDate.fadeIn();
    } else {
      $eventDate
        .fadeOut()
        .filter(tagged[$(this).val()])
        .fadeIn();
    }
  });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hrsxb6wq/